# How does ping work on Fedora without setuid and capabilities?

Tags: security, setuid, capabilities

As far as I know, `ping` needs to create a [raw socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket#Types) (which needs either root access or `cap_net_raw` capabilities).

From my understanding the trend these last years has been to remove [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) binaries and replaced them with [capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security).

However when I look at the `ping` binary on my Fedora 32, it doesn't look to have any:

```
$ ls -la $(which ping)
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 82960 May 18 10:26 /usr/bin/ping
$ sudo getcap -v $(which ping)
/usr/bin/ping
$
```

Does ping need to open raw socket on fedora? Or is there another way to give it the permission to open a raw socket?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/EnableSysctlPingGroupRange answers your question:

> Enable the Linux kernel's net.ipv4.ping_group_range parameter to cover all groups. This will let all users on the operating system create ICMP Echo sockets without using setuid binaries, or having the CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW file capabilities.

Cross-reference detail

- Targeted release: [Fedora 31](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/31)
- Last updated: 2019-08-13
- Tracker bug: #[1740809](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1740809)
- Release notes tracker: #[376](https://pagure.io/fedora-docs/release-notes/issue/376)

The [sysctl documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) writes,

> **ping_group_range** - 2 INTEGERS
>
> Restrict `ICMP_PROTO` datagram sockets to
> users in the group range.     The default is "`1 0`", meaning, that nobody
> (not even root) may   create ping sockets.  Setting it to "`100 100`"
> would grant permissions   to the single group. "`0 4294967295`" would
> enable it for the world, "`100 4294967295`" would enable it for the
> users, but not daemons.

An older [code example](https://sturmflut.github.io/linux/ubuntu/2015/01/17/unprivileged-icmp-sockets-on-linux/) demonstrates the use of this feature, and in particular shows that a socket is created with the `IPPROTO_ICMP` flag to identify that it will be used for raw ICMP

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP)
```

Comment: How does this work?  I've done no investigation into this, but I would have thought that attempting to create a raw socket without CAP_NET_RAW would fail, which would give the kernel no opportunity to selectively permit a program to generate ICMP Echo packets because the program would fail before it gets that far.  Is there a separate syscall to send Echo Request?  Or does the kernel allow anyone to open a raw socket then check permissions only when a read or write is attempted?

Comment: @user3553031 answer updated

Comment: Ah, it doesn't use a raw socket.  I didn't realize that there was a separate option for sending ICMP from userspace.

Answer (score 14):

from [Fedora 31](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/31/ChangeSet) the kernel parameter `net.ipv4.ping_group_range`  has been set to cover all groups.

This will let all users on the operating system create `ICMP Echo` sockets without using `setuid` binaries, or having the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` and `CAP_NET_RAW` file capabilities.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ping_group_range

net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0   2147483647
```