# ping inside netns requires sudo (Fedora)

Tags: fedora, namespace, network-namespaces

Using fedora 32, I launched a shell inside a network namespace using

```
sudo ip netns add net0
sudo ip netns exec net0 sudo -u fred /usr/bin/bash
```

I configured the network links and firewall to enable ping.
When I try to ping as non-root I get:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8                       
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

But if I try to ping with sudo, it works. Why?

Answer (score 7):

See related question [How does ping work on Fedora without setuid and capabilities?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592911/how-does-ping-work-on-fedora-without-setuid-and-capabilities)

and Links

https://lwn.net/Articles/422330/

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/EnableSysctlPingGroupRange

For security reasons, Fedora no longer user setuid/capabilities in order
to allow non-root to use ping. Instead, they use a recent kernel feature
which lets the administrator enable ping use by gid.

In a normal shell:

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ping_group_range      
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0   2147483647
```

But in a fresh shell inside a network netspace:

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ping_group_range
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 1   0
```

So the mechanism which enables non-root users to use ping on fedora is disabled
by default when you create a new netns. To fix this, simply set the sysctl value
inside your netns:

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ping_group_range="0 2147483647"
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0 2147483647
$ ping 8.8.8.8
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=40 time=20 ms
```