# How does one modify the ping command

Tags: linux, networking, package-management, ping

I am somewhat new to kernel programming but am trying to modify the functionality of the ping command in Linux. I am using Ubuntu, which I believe uses iputils to create the binary ping command located in bin on my machine. However, I also found a ping.c file in the net/ipv4 and net/ipv6 folders of the Linux source code. So my main questions are:

What is the ping.c file doing in the net folders?
How would one modify the ping command, seeing as it is a part of iputils? More specifically, I have pulled iputils from [here](https://github.com/iputils/iputils), but I don't really know how to compile it/reinstall a custom package after I have modified the source code.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The `ping` binary is indeed included with `iputils`. If you want to modify `ping`, that is the place to look. You can build the program, using the instructions included with iputils.

The `ping.c` file in the linux source code implements a '[Ping socket](https://lwn.net/Articles/443051/)'. That is an innovation that allows a user to send and receive ICMP messages without special privileges.

Comment: just to note, the reason a user can send/receive ping is because `ping` binary had `setuid` root permission and in modern OSes it has `cap_net_raw+ep` capabilities. Recently in Fedora a new way has been applied. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592913/254422