# Why ping works without capability and setuid

Tags: setuid, capabilities, setcap

I learned from [here](http://unixetc.co.uk/2016/05/30/linux-capabilities-and-ping/) that there's 2 ways to control privileged activities: `setuid` and `capability`.

But when I'm playing around with `ping` on my machine, it seems that it can bypass these 2 mechanism.

First, confirm that on my machine `/usr/bin/ping` has `cap_net_raw` capability and it use `SOCK_RAW`:

```bsh
$ ll /usr/bin/ping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72K Jan 31  2020 /usr/bin/ping

$ getcap /usr/bin/ping
/usr/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep

$ strace -e socket ping <some-ip>
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 5
```

Copying the binary will drop the capability but it still works:

```bsh
$ cp /usr/bin/ping ~

$ ll ~/ping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 72K Nov  4 16:54 /home/user/ping

$ getcap ~/ping
[empty result]

$ ~/ping <some-ip>
[it works]
```

I'm using `Ubuntu 20.04` and `5.4.0-52-generic`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a recent Linux system, [ping doesn't need any privileges for its most basic operation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592911/how-does-ping-work-on-fedora-without-setuid-and-capabilities), which is to send ICMP echo request messages and receive responding echo reply messages.

Ubuntu 20.04 has two implementations of ping. The default one, from [iputils-ping](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/iputils-ping), is installed setcap `CAP_NET_RAW` but works for ICMP echo without privileges. The one from [inetutils-ping](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/inetutils-ping) is installed setuid root but also works for ICMP echo without privileges. Both use an ICMP socket, which is permitted without privileges:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3
```

I can't reproduce the use of a netlink socket for a basic ping on either of these implementations, with or without privileges.